# Basic angular JS with ng-app is not working for me

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to write my first angular JS with ng-app with simple math function and it not working for me without any error. Not sure where it went wrong

test    10 + 20 = {{ 10+20 }}

I tried with <script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.2/…> and it worked, local path still not working. How to validate I have valid angular.js in my path and to debug it loading properly or not.

Comment: Do not try to use comments to *add information to a post*: [Edit the post!](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) Even with posts by other users.

Comment: Please post the complete code to reproduce the issue.